# changing button using event listener

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a list of button elements that I am trying to attach an `eventlistener` to such that, whenever it is clicked, the `INNERHTML` changes. My code is below. The `else if` statement never triggers.
Can some help me understand what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

```js
let editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("editBtns");

    for(let btn =0; btn<editButtons.length; btn++ ){
        editButtons[btn].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleButton(this, this.previousSibling);
        });
    }
    
function toggleButton(btnElement, spanElement){
    if(btnElement.innerHTML= 'edit'){
        btnElement.innerHTML= 'update';
    } 
    else if(btnElement.innerHTML= 'update'){
        btnElement.innerHTML= 'edit';
    }
}
```

Comment: should be `btnElement.innerHTML ===  'edit'`. Notice the difference between`===`, `==` and `=`

Comment: See the comment above. Also, btnElement.innerHTML = 'edit' will return 'edit'-a non empty string, which is converted inside if() as true. That's why your else if never triggers. :)

Comment: Ah rookie mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So the problem here is that your if statement is using the assignment operator which is `=` instead of the comparison operator which is `==`. In order for the `if...else` statement to work, replace it with `==`. Something like this will suffice

```
let editButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("editBtns");
for(let btn =0; btn<editButtons.length; btn++ ){
    editButtons[btn].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        toggleButton(this);
    });
}

function toggleButton(btnElement){
    if(btnElement.innerHTML == 'update'){
       btnElement.innerHTML= 'edit';
    }
    else
       btnElement.innerHTML= 'update';
    }
}
```